# which python vs PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, linux, python-requests, environment, pythonpath

If I type in `which python` I get: `/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/python`
If I type in `echo $PYTHONPATH` I get: `/home/USER/terrain_planning/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Should that not be the same? And is it not better to set it: `usr/lib/python/`
How would I do that? Add it to the PYTHONPATH or set the PYTHONPATH to that? But how to set `which python`?

Comment: PYTHONPATH contains nonstandard paths to your python libraries. ˋwhich pythonˋ is the path to your Python executable. The two are not related and you should *not* try to make them the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing 2 environment variables:

- `PATH` where `which` looks up for executables when they're accessed by name only. This variable is a list (colon/semi-colon separated depending on the platform) of directories containing executables. Not python specific. `which python` just looks in this variable and prints the full path
- `PYTHONPATH` is python-specific list of directories (colon/semi-colon separated like `PATH`) where python looks for packages that aren't installed directly in the python distribution. The name & format is very close to system/shell `PATH` variable on purpose, but it's not used by the operating system at all, just by python.

Comment: Hi thanks for the good answer. 
What would happen if I set the PATH to /usr/lib/python ?
And how would I do that?

Comment: setting `PYTHONPATH` to the python installation would have no effect as there are no python modules to import at this location.

Answer (score 1):

`which python` is the path to your python interpreter. `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable where your Python program can search for modules to import.

[See section 1.2](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html)

*Should that not be the same? And is it not better to set it: usr/lib/python/ How would I do that? Add it to the PYTHONPATH or set the PYTHONPATH to that? But how to set which python?*

No they are not the same. You don't really need to modify the path to your Python interpreter. To modify the PYTHONPATH, you can set it in a shell, or from within a Python program by using `sys.path`

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
sys.path.append("another/path/to/search")
```